# buenas, estoy aprendiendo c++ y tengo una duda con respecto a los punteros a funciones por que en este código la salida es 1 1

Tags: c++, funciones, punteros

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void chance();

int main(){
    void (*prt_chance)(void) = NULL;
    prt_chance = chance;   
    cout<<*prt_chance<<endl;   
    cout<<prt_chance<<endl;   
    return 0;
}

void chance() {  
    cout<<"hello world"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Puedes revisar en el assembler generado en [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GEPa7x84P) cual `operator<<` esta llamando. Ya que no hay un operador que acepte como parámetro un `void (*)(void)`, toma una sobrecarga en la que pueda hacer un cast implicito, en este caso `operator<<(bool)`.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta y por esa herramienta (godbolt) no sabia que existía me será muy útil, saludos.